# Confusion when appending to slice

Tags: go

Can someone explain why in the first example if appending to y changes also x but in the second example it doesnt?

```
    x := make([]int, 0, 4)
    x = append(x, 1, 2, 3, 4) //len(x)=4 and cap(x)=4
    y := x[:2]                //Len(y)=2 and cap(y)=4

    y = append(y, 30, 40)

    fmt.Println("x:", x)
    fmt.Println("y:", y)

    //x: [1 2 30 40]
    //y: [1 2 30 40]
```

```
    x := make([]int, 0, 4)
    x = append(x, 1, 2, 3, 4) //len(x)=4 and cap(x)=4
    y := x[:2]                //Len(y)=2 and cap(y)=4

    y = append(y, 30, 40,50)

    fmt.Println("x:", x)
    fmt.Println("y:", y)

    //x: [1 2 3 4]
    //y: [1 2 30 40 50]
```

And how is this affected by the capacity? For example if I change the capacity to 5

```
x := make([]int, 0, 5)
x = append(x, 1, 2, 3, 4) 
y := x[:2]             

y = append(y, 30, 40, 50)

fmt.Println("x:", x)
fmt.Println("y:", y)

//x: [1 2 30 40]
//y: [1 2 30 40 50]
```

then it seems to work but then I would assume that x also contains 50?

Comment: Because in the first example the cap is not enough for the appended values to fit and therefore a new backing array needed to be allocated, leaving the old backing array untouched. In the second example the cap was enough to fit the appended values into the backing array so the old backing array was kept and re-used.

Comment: calling `append()` doubles the slice's capacity if there isn't enough space. In 2) and 3) if you print `cap(y)` to be 8 (twice the original capacity of 4), which is sufficient enough to hold the values provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `y` has the same underlying array as `x` and as you append to `y` and everything fits into that array `x` is also affected.

In the second case `y` has the same underlying array as `x` as first, but when you try to append new values the underlying array is not enough so a new one is allocated and `x` is unaffacted.

In the third case it's similar to the first one - when you append things to `y` it affects x as well. When you print the contents of `x` the `len` of `x` is took into consideration so only the first 4 values are printed (x has a length of 4, even though it has the capacity of 5).